# Storing UIEdgeInsets in NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, uiedgeinsets

I am trying to create a list of `UIEdgeInsets` instances in Objective-C. Since they are not `id` type, I couldn't add them into an array.

What I want to do is something like this:

```
NSArray *contentInsets = @[{10, 20, 30, 40}, {10, 10, 10, 10}, ...];
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use following to store UIEdgeInsets in NSArray:

```
NSStringFromUIEdgeInsets
```

For example:

```
NSArray *contentInsets = @[NSStringFromUIEdgeInsets(UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 20, 30, 40)), NSStringFromUIEdgeInsets(UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10)), ...];
```

And to retrieve back:

```
UIEdgeInsetsFromString
```